# Count max values compared with previous array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I try to count the number of values in a row that are equal are greater to MAX() value of a (part) of the column above.

For example: compared to the 3 cells above itself. In E comes the 'count'. 
i marked the cells it should count with *.

[image]

My final array is about 200x5000...
I already tried (cell E4 in example) stuff like:

```
{=SUM(IF(A4:D4>=MAX(OFFSET(A1,ROW($1:$4)-1,0,3,1)),1,0))}

{=COUNTIF(A4:D4,">="&MAX(OFFSET(A1,0,ROW($1:$4)-1,3,1)))}
```

Hoping that the ROW() & OFFSET() function would split the MAX function over the columns... But none give a decent result.
I can of course split the MAX() over 200 different columns on a different sheet. But I'm getting nightmares because i can't get it done in a single array formula.

Answer (score 2):

If you are strictly looking for a Worksheet Function based approach, possibly this may not be the recommended solution, however here I have used a small UDF (User Defined Function) to simplify the task.

This UDF takes in a Range and Returns an Array of Max of each column in that range.

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to access VBA Editor. Insert a Module from the Insert Menu. Now put the following code into it.

```
Function Ret_Arr(inpt As Range) As Variant


Dim v As Variant

ReDim v(1 To inpt.Columns.Count)

For i = 1 To inpt.Columns.Count

    v(i) = Application.Max(inpt.Columns(i))

Next i

Ret_Arr = v


End Function
```

Do note that there are no much validations put in this basic code to make it robust just in case.

This takes in Range and returns an Array of Max from each column that you can use in your array formula.

Save the VBA code and Worksheet as XLSM Macro Enabled Worksheet in case you are using Excel 2007 and above.

In this example sample data is in Cells A1:D8. In E2 put the following formula and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the Formula Bar to create an Array Formula.

The formula shall be enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula

```
=SUM(IF($A2:$D2>=Ret_Arr($A$1:D1),1,0))
```

Now for each range above the Ret_Arr shall return the array of Max of each column. If you do not pass correct range to the Ret_Arr then you may get erroneous results. So if your columns in question are A thru D make sure to pass same range of columns A thru D to the UDF.

[image]

Comment: Working,, perfect 10   ☺

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with the VBA, it is a elegant solution. But I'm still surprised it can't be done formula based.

Answer (score 0):

In `E4`, **array formula****:

`=COUNT(1/(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(A$1:D3)^0),N(A4:D4>=A$1:D3))=ROWS(A$1:D3)))`

Copy down as required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*